Google Sign-In Failure: Unable to Change SHA1 in GCP, Error Indicates Entity Already Exists
I have an Android application along with a project in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for Google Sign-In. During testing, it functions properly with the debug SHA1 fingerprint. Now, I intend to deploy it online. I switched from test mode to production mode and updated the SHA1 fingerprint to the release SHA1. However, it's not functioning as expected. Some devices can successfully sign in initially but encounter issues upon subsequent attempts. Additionally, many devices fail to log in at all during the initial attempt. The following two error messages are encountered:

Error message 1 (Error 10)


Error: During begin sign in, failure response from one tap: 10: Developer console is not set up correctly.


Error message 2(user cancel)


Error: activity is cancelled by the user.

Subsequently, I attempted to change the SHA1 to the Google Play SHA1 fingerprint, but I encountered an error when attempting to save it. The error message reads:

Save failed.  Requested entity already exists.
Tracking number: XXXX.


Try: Switch back to test mode and input the Google Play SHA1 Fingerprint.
Excepted: Successfully save the new SHA1.
Result: Save failed.



Try: Revert back to debug SHA1.
Excepted: Successfully save the changes.
Result:  Changes saved successfully.



Try: Investigate if there are any existing projects with identical SHA1 fingerprints causing the "Requested entity already exists" issue.
Excepted: ...
Result: No such project.


@Robert Thank you for the reminder. I have posted the error message as code.
